# Access Denied for Glue_Job in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I tried to use resource aws_glue_job, but as soon as it's prepared to be launched, an error is shown as follows:

```
│ Error: error creating Glue Job (job): AccessDeniedException: Account 411xxxxxxxx (Account id) is denied access.
│ 
│   with aws_glue_job.job,
│   on main.tf line 94, in resource "aws_glue_job" "job":
│   94: resource "aws_glue_job" "job" {
```

I checked the policies and apparently is okay. What might be doing it?

Comment: Is this cross-account? Also you might want to check if it is available in the region you want to create it in.

Comment: @MarkoE it's not cross-account. I'm doing it on us-east-2 region. I created all the rest in this same region like bucket, crawler, etc

Comment: Without more context it's almost impossible to make an assumption let alone answer the question. Can you add the code to the question?

Comment: We're having the same problem since yesterday in region us-east-1. Nothing changed, suddenly we cannot start our Glue jobs anymore with this error: 
Failed to start job
[gluestudio-service.us-east-1.amazonaws.com] startJobRun: AccessDeniedException: Account <MY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER> is denied access. (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: <MY_REQUEST_ID>; Proxy: null)

Comment: @mikey I silves by creatina a New account and It worked. In my case, the account was used for testa. If your account is used for the Company I recommend you to talk tô te support team from AWS and give further details about it

Comment: @FelipeLobatinho We have created a new account. First, it did work. After rolling out our components via Terraform, it was blocked again (for all sub-accounts of our org although only one accounts has been provisioned with Terraform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my issue was solved by creating and using a new account. This account being used previously was for test, that is why I did have no problems by changing It to a new  one

Answer (score 0):

We still have the same problem; even with sub-accounts of a totally new account. It seems like more and more people have the same issue:

- [Access Denied for Glue_Job in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73126691/access-denied-for-glue-job-in-terraform)
- [AWSGlue AccessDeniedException, Status Code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233710/awsglue-accessdeniedexception-status-code-400)
- [Access Denied When Create AWS Glue Crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73202225/access-denied-when-create-aws-glue-crawler)
- [AWS Glue gives AccessDeniedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254895/aws-glue-gives-accessdeniedexception)
- https://repost.aws/questions/QUhxdKlj4VSF-dzTXo7Xt3Iw/aws-glue-access-denied-exception-status-code-400
- https://repost.aws/questions/QU7wLjCe0rR_Wp5VFgVKTIbg/unable-to-run-create-glue-job-from-root-user-getting-access-denied-exception

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Logging with TF_LOG ([debbuging_terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/debugging)) helped me to be sure that this was not being caused by anything that I could fix.
If you have already verified policies (For example I attached AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess policy to the role creating glue job) and you have also verified that aws provider is correct, see: [provider](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/resource-provider). You can open a ticket with billing & account and they will escalate this properly. They helped me and now I am able to create glue jobs again with the same account.