# AWS Glue gives AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

When I'm trying to create Glue Crawler, I get this error, even though I have full administration access on IAM

```
{"service":"AWSGlue","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"AccessDeniedException","requestId":"c1a564e7-d012-4e96-946f-a32be287e8ba","errorMessage":"Account 1234567890 is denied access.","type":"AwsServiceError"}
```

Comment: Do you have any 'permissions boundaries' configured for your user in IAM? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html
Similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73202225/access-denied-when-create-aws-glue-crawler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open IAM

- Policy Name: GlueActions (Type :Customer Inline)[
  --- "Statement":[

  ```
    "Resource":
               ...
               "arn:aws:glue:*xxx:catalog"
               ...
               ],
              "Effect":"Allow"
                  ]
  ```

Ensure the above "catalog" is present else create the whole Customer Inline JSON

Comment: you can also get the whol json auto populated.

Comment: also ensure that other relevant AWS Glue permissions are enabled