# ACCESS DENIED error when trying to create a Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to create a Glue job in an account that has full access to all resources

The script gets generated but when I try and save it  I get the following error

**[gluestudio-service.us-east-1.amazonaws.com] createJob: AccessDeniedException: Account XXXXX is denied access.**

The role I am using has nothing fancy in it and has full access to glue and all S3 resources.

Its not an organisational account

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

I am using the managed **AWSGlueServiceRole** as well as the **AmazonS3FullAccess** roles

I have added the follwoing

````
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:UseGlueStudio",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListGroups",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "glue:SearchTables",
                "glue:GetConnections",
                "glue:GetJobs",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "glue:BatchStopJobRun",
                "glue:GetSecurityConfigurations",
                "glue:DeleteJob",
                "glue:GetDatabases",
                "glue:CreateConnection",
                "glue:GetSchema",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetMapping",
                "glue:CreateJob",
                "glue:DeleteConnection",
                "glue:CreateScript",
                "glue:UpdateConnection",
                "glue:GetConnection",
                "glue:StartJobRun",
                "glue:GetJobRun",
                "glue:UpdateJob",
                "glue:GetPlan",
                "glue:GetJobRuns",
                "glue:GetTags",
                "glue:GetJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AWSGlueServiceRole*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "glue.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}```
````

Comment: can you post your IAM Policy, have you added glue:UseGlueStudio?

Comment: Hi there
I've got "glue:*" in the policy
When adding the switch you siggested glue:UseGlueStudio  the policy errors

Comment: I've followed this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/setting-up.html#getting-started-min-privs and getting the same error

Comment: Please update your question with IAM policy used.

Comment: Seems like a few people having the same issues 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233710/awsglue-accessdeniedexception-status-code-400

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/setting-up.html#getting-started-iam-permissions), for glue studio, you need to use `AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess`. Have ou tried that?

Comment: I have - same error

Comment: Is there an explicit deny policy set for your user that assumes the role? If so it preceeds the explicit allow in the roles policy. Can you share the policies attached to the User that assumes the role.

Comment: There are no explicit denies - the policies attached are as detailed in the post - its also a root user

Answer (score 0):

Add Trusted Policy like the following in the Role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com",
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Like this?   
No difference
```{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com",
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<myAccountNumber>:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}```

Comment: have you attached a resource based policy on your Data Catalog resource?

Comment: No data catalog in use